# YAMLException: duplicated mapping key from a markdown file using gray-matter

Tags: next.js, yaml, markdown

I am parsing a set Markdown files (.md) and converting them to html via Gray-Matter as blog posts in NextJs. I've got a set of sources, including a name and url, which I wanted to map out on the FE when rendering. It works fine with a single entry, but I get an exception when trying to add more than one.

Markdown:

```
title: 'Blog Title'
date: '2022-08-29'
snippet: 'TBD'
image: '/help.jpg'
sources: {
  "urls": [
    {
      "site": {
        "name": "Site Name 1",
        "url": "https://www.google.com"
      },
      "site": {
        "name": "Site Name 2",
        "url": "https://www.google.com"
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

Blog main content

Exception:

```
YAMLException: duplicated mapping key at line 16, column 8:
          },
```

Where line 16 is the last }, after the url value.

This is the code I am using to map the data:

```
postData.sources.urls.map(items => 
  <ul>
   <li><a target="_blank" href={items.site.url}>{items.site.name}</a></li>
  </ul>
)
```

Is this a syntax issue, or a bigger issue?

Comment: Can you link to an example repo/pen/something demonstrating your problem? There's a lot going on here, I think I could help if I had a better grasp of all the code at play.

Comment: The object inside the `urls` array has a duplicate key `site`. You probably meant to have those as separate entries in the array instead.

Answer (score 1):

I was overthinking my JSON structure. I changed it to

```
sites: [
  { 
    name: "Site Name 1", 
    url: "www.google.com" 
  },
  { 
    name: "Site Name 2", 
    url: "www.google.com" 
  },
]
```

and everything works fine.

Comment: how your code transform markdown into html?

Comment: I use Remark: https://www.npmjs.com/package/remark